# Access to a row-major parameters in C# from C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I try to access a coordinate system parameters from a C++ dll into my C# project.
The function declaration in C++ is the following:

```
unsigned int GetUCS(IUnknown* document, unsigned int id, double (&frame)[16]);
```

I need help with the frame parameter which is a row-major:

```
  [Right_x, Up_x, Forward_x, Translation_x]
  [Right_y, Up_y, Forward_y, Translation_y]
  [Right_z, Up_z, Forward_z, Translation_z]
  [0,       0,    0,         1            ]
```

In my C# project I must have something like:

```
  [DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
  private static extern uint GetUCS([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object document, uint id, double(frame)?));
```

to receive the frame and make some 3D transformations based on it. Thank you!

Comment: Try `[In, Out] double[] frame` and pass an already allocated `double[16]`. PS: CharSet = CharSet.Unicode seems useless here.

Comment: @simon Surely this should be `[In, Out] double[,]` and then allocate it with `new double[4, 4]`

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test your response!!

Comment: A one-dimensional array in C++ has no definition for "row-major".  Not in C# either.  Computing the index with column + row*width is the obvious way to map it, in effect what happens when a compiler does it.  In fact the faster way to do it in C#, multi-dimensional arrays are a lot uglier than jagged arrays at runtime.

Comment: A double is 8 bytes you are reading 16 * 8 = 128 bytes in consecutive memory.  It doesn't make a difference in the if you declare it double or double[] except if you want to put results directly into a single dimension array or double dimension array.  The resul;ts are going to be unmanaged so I would use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]double[] frame

Comment: @Hans Presumably what is meant is that the 1d array is interpreted as a row major 2d array

Comment: @jdweng that leads to _System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException
  HResult=0x80131535
  Message=Cannot marshal 'parameter #3': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Arrays can only be marshaled as LPArray, ByValArray, or SafeArray)_

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use a C# multidimensional array like this:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
private static extern uint GetUCS(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object document, 
    uint id, 
    [In, Out] double[,] frame
);
```

You'd allocate the array in your C# code like this:

```
double[,] frame = new double[4, 4];
```

You could equally use `double[] frame` allocated as `new double[16]` which would match the C++ code literally, but then you'd lose out on the ability to access the matrix naturally in your C# code.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I'm curios if I will receive the correct UCS param. Come back with results and conclusions!

Comment: C# multimensional arrays are contiguous and arranged in row major order, so this will behave as desired